# instance.__dict__ in django templating language

Tags: django, django-templates

I often find it useful to use `instance.__dict__` to display properties of an object in python.

I'm trying to examine an field object in a django template, is there a way to replicate this behaviour in django templating language?

I would expect something like `{{ my_object.__dict }}`, but i can't see anything in the docs.

Comment: make a instance method and return the dict version of it. Then call it from template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

## 1) Model method:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __str__(self):
        return self.field1
```

and then you can call `{{ instance.to_dict }}` in your template.

## 2) Template filter

```
@register.filter
def to_dict(instance):
    return instance.__dict__
```

and then you can call `{{ instance|to_dict }}`

Note: You must activate the template filters and create them by following [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [pprint filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#pprint):

```
{{ my_object|pprint }}
```